# preserve white space in options text of a select for string created by java

Tags: html

Server side, I build a list of strings which are the option text of an html select multiple.

Every string is the result of the concatenation of four strings. First, second and third have a length=5. Third string has a variable length, so I complete its length to 19 chars with white spaces:

```
 StringUtils.rightPad(data.toUpperCase(), 19, " ");
```

Nevertheless, in my html page, these whites spaces are removed.

I have looked for similar problems in this web and others, I have tried with & nbsp;, \u0020, I have tried with css style white-space:pre-wrap;, I have tried a lot of things but white spaces are not preserved.

Any one knows how to solve this problem without javascript? only with html/styles.

Thank you, regards

Answer (score 1):

The default styling in  webpages is to collapse whitespace, you can easily change this with the `white-space` property in CSS:

```
p {
 white-space: pre;
}
```

The values `pre` and `pre-wrap` preserve whitespace, the difference between them being that `pre` will only wrap the text on line-breaks, whereas `pre-wrap` will wrap on all whitespace characters (like regular text. Your question states that you have tried this and it did not work, however I have tested this code and it worked fine for me (using Google Chrome) and [the W3C reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) says that it works in all major browsers, therefore I suspect it is a mistake in implementation, try again and double-check you are applying styles to the correct class and there are no specificity issues.